# For what values of $a\in \mathbb{C}$, matrix $A$ is positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

My task is to find a value $a\in\mathbb{C}$ such that the matrix

> $$A=\left(\begin{array}(1 & a & a \\ a & 1 & a\\ a & a &
>  1\end{array}\right)$$

is positive definite for all $\textbf{x}\in\mathbb{C}^3, \textbf{x}\neq\textbf{0}$. I tried to do the following:

$\langle A\textbf{x}, \textbf{x}\rangle = x\overline{x}+y\overline{y}+z\overline{z} + a(\overline{x}y+x\overline{y}+\overline{x}z+x\overline{z}+\overline{y}z+y\overline{z})$, where

$\textbf{x}=(x,y,z).$ Matrix $A$ is p.d. if $\langle A\textbf{x}, \textbf{x}\rangle>0$ for all non-zero vectors. I get:

$\langle A\textbf{x}, \textbf{x}\rangle = \langle\textbf{x},\textbf{x}\rangle + a(\overline{x}y+x\overline{y}+\overline{x}z+x\overline{z}+\overline{y}z+y\overline{z})$. I know $\langle\textbf{x},\textbf{x}\rangle\geq 0$, so now I must find $a$ such that

$a(\overline{x}y+x\overline{y}+\overline{x}z+x\overline{z}+\overline{y}z+y\overline{z})>0$. The sum inside the brackets is a real number $r=\overline{x}y+x\overline{y}+\overline{x}z+x\overline{z}+\overline{y}z+y\overline{z}$. So I need $a$ such that

$$ar>0,$$

By selecting $a=r$, I get $r^2>0$ but now $a$ is dependent on $r$ and I'm stuck. How to proceed?

Comment: what can you infer about $|a|<1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$ A = a\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}+(1-a)\cdot I $$
where the matrix made by $1s$ only is a rank-$1$ matrix with eigenvalues $3,0,0$.

It follows that the eigenvalues of $A$ are $2a+1,1-a,1-a$, so $A$ is positive definite iff $2a+1>0$ and $1-a>0$, hence iff $\color{red}{-\frac{1}{2}<a<1}$.

Comment: One question. How did you solve the eigenvalues? :) Did you simply calculate the characteristic polynomial and solve the root values or did you use some other technique here? :)

Comment: @jjepsuomi: I used the fact that the eigenvalues of $M+k\cdot I$ are always given by the eigenvalues of $M$ increased by $k$, since the identity matrix commutes with every matrix.

Comment: On the other hand, it is trivial that the $3\times 3$ matrix made by $1s$ only has an eigenvalue equal to three, and the other eigenvalues are zero since such a matrix has rank one.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! :)

Answer (score 2):

The determinant is $\det A=1+2a^3-3a^2$ and by Sylvester's criterion the conditions are
$$
\begin{cases}
1-a^2>0\\[4px]
2a^3-3a^2+1>0
\end{cases}
$$
as the first principal minor is positive.

> Since the second inequality is the same as $(a-1)^2(2a+1)>0$ and the solutions for the first one are $-1<a<1$, we get the final condition $\displaystyle-\frac{1}{2}<a<1$

Comment: appreciate your help!